# Нет ответа от сервера при записи в выходящий поток

Tags: java, сокет, клиент-сервер, io

Реализован простой сервер . В качестве клиента использую программу cURL работаю с ней через cmd. Почему то не приходит ответ когда хочу выйти отправляю такую команду - curl -i http://localhost:9000/?msg=Exit -  вроде записывает данные но они не приходят  от сервера не пойму причину. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = null;
        try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9000)) {
            while (!server.isClosed()) {
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                try (OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
                     while (in.ready()) {
                         str = in.readLine();
                         if (str.contains("Exit")) {
                             out.write("GoodBye My Dear friend\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
                             server.close();
                         }
                        System.out.println(str);
                     }
                  out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы закрываете сокет (остановкой сервера), не отправив клиенту `HTTP/1.1...`

```
try (OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
    while (in.ready()) {
        str = in.readLine();
        if (str.contains("Exit")) {
            // Вот сюда нужно добавить HTTP/1.1
            out.write("GoodBye My Dear friend\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
            server.close();
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
}
```